# Create a class constructor from scratch in ByteBuddy

Tags: java, bytecode-manipulation, byte-buddy

I am trying to create a Java class from scratch using ByteBuddy. A class is supposed to have a bunch of private final properties and one constructor which initializes them with the arguments passed. I started with:

```
DynamicType.Builder<?> builder = new ByteBuddy()
                .subclass(Object.class)
                .implement(Serializable.class)
                .modifiers(Visibility.PUBLIC, TypeManifestation.FINAL)
                .name("Structure");

// for each property to be declared
builder = builder.defineField(bindingName, bindingType, visibility.PRIVATE, FieldManifestation.FINAL);
// end of for

builder = builder.defineConstructor(Visibility.PUBLIC)
                .withParameters(bindings)
                .intercept(/* Some implementation is supposed to go here*/);
```

I have several questions:

1. Does ByteBuddy provide some suitable Implementation for that out-of-the-box?
2. Is there somewhere an overview of ByteBuddy Implementation classes, provided out-of-the-box?
3. If there is no such Implementation out-of-the-box, I'd be appreciated for some hints on how to make my own Implementation instance serving my purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement such a constructor by a combination of `MethodCall` and `FieldAccessor`:

```
DynamicType.Builder<?> builder = ...;
Implementation interceptor = StubMethod.INSTANCE;

// for each field
builder = builder.defineField(bindingName, 
              bindingType, visibility.PRIVATE, FieldManifestation.FINAL);
interceptor = FieldAccessor.ofField(bindingName)
                  .setsArgumentAt( ... )
                  .andThen(interceptor);

interceptor = MethodCall.invoke( ... ).andThen(interceptor);
```

The method call must invoke a specific constructor of either the instrumented class or the super class constructor (might be the default constructor of `Object`). The argument index needs to be the index of the argument that is assigned to the field (zero-based).

Answer (score 0):

Didn't found any ready implementation, so end up writing my own. It is not finalized, but it works. Here it is:

```
final class ConstructorImplementation implements Implementation {

    static private final class BCA implements ByteCodeAppender {

        @Override
        public Size apply(MethodVisitor methodVisitor, Context implementationContext, MethodDescription instrumentedMethod) {
            TypeDescription instrumentedType = implementationContext.getInstrumentedType();
            Iterator<? extends ParameterDescription> iterator = instrumentedMethod.getParameters().iterator();

            List<StackManipulation> insr = new ArrayList<>();
            insr.add(MethodVariableAccess.loadThis());
            insr.add(MethodInvocation.invoke(TypeDescription.OBJECT.getDeclaredMethods().get(0)));
            for (FieldDescription.InDefinedShape field : instrumentedType.getDeclaredFields()) {
                ParameterDescription.InDefinedShape param = iterator.next().asDefined();
                insr.add(MethodVariableAccess.loadThis());
                insr.add(MethodVariableAccess.load(param));
                insr.add(FieldAccess.forField(field).write());
            }
            insr.add(MethodReturn.VOID);

            StackManipulation.Size operandStackSize = new StackManipulation.Compound(
                    insr
            ).apply(methodVisitor, implementationContext);
            return new Size(operandStackSize.getMaximalSize(),
                    instrumentedMethod.getStackSize());
        }
    }

    private final BCA bca;

    public ConstructorImplementation() {
        bca = new BCA();
    }

    @Override
    public ByteCodeAppender appender(Target implementationTarget) {
        return bca;
    }

    @Override
    public InstrumentedType prepare(InstrumentedType instrumentedType) {
        return instrumentedType;
    }
}
```

I'll leave this question opened for a while, for the case somebody knows a better solution for that.